# Find common directory path

Tags: strings, file-system, swift, linux

I answered the problem of Find common directory path from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_common_directory_path#R).

The problem consists of passing  `'/home/user1/tmp/coverage/test'`,
 `'/home/user1/tmp/covert/operator'`, and `'/home/user1/tmp/coven/members'` to a function, the resultant path should be the valid directory `'/home/user1/tmp'` and not the longest common string `'/home/user1/tmp/cove'`.

The solution (the working code) is:

```
import Foundation


func getPrefix(_ text:[String]) -> String? {
    var common:String = text[0]
    for i in text {
        common = i.commonPrefix(with: common)
    }
    return common
}

var test = ["/home/user1/tmp/coverage/test", 
 "/home/user1/tmp/covert/operator",
 "/home/user1/tmp/coven/members"]

var output:String = getPrefix(test)!
print(output)
```

Could the above code be further optimized?

Comment: Looks to me that if your code doesn't return the right result, it doesn't need to be optimized but to be fixed: that would make your question off-topic for Code Review and you would have to ask that on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: I don't understand, the code works! What do you mean?

Comment: The code *runs* but doesn't resurn the right result. I think this question belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The result should be `/home/user1/tmp`, and this is what I have in my terminal. What do you get? I am running it on the REPL.

Comment: Ah! I get `/home/user1/tmp/cove`. See my [screenshot of my Playground](http://take.ms/HyPFK).

Comment: And looking at your code, I see that you don't handle the last "/" and that's why you get the whole ".../tmp/cove" instead of  ".../tmp". It can't work.

Comment: Here my screenshot, perhaps a bug only in linux? https://imgur.com/a/gxYWo

Comment: Look at my REPL, same as with my Playground: http://take.ms/MM2dx // If you're sure that you're using the same code as in your question, then yeah, maybe a bug with `commonPrefix(with:)` in Foundation on Linux. It would be worth digging into it (it's open source and on GitHub).

Comment: Just compiled the same code and the result is similar: https://imgur.com/a/gxYWo Thanks for the help, will report it in github.

Comment: You're welcome. Worth being reported indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Naming

Good names can greatly improve the readability of a program.
Many of the names in the posted code can be improved:

- `getPrefix`: the function returns the *common* prefix. It would be good to include that important clarifying detail in the name.

  - If you intend to return the common parent directory, I would call the function `getCommonParent`.
- `text`: the parameter is not just any text, it's an array of *paths*, so `paths` would be a better name that conveys the intention.
- `i`: is fine in simple counting loops, but when you iterate over values that have a meaningful name, it's better to use that, for example in this example `path`.
- `test` is also an overly generic name, instead of the more descriptive `paths`

#### Algorithm

The implementation will call `commonPrefix` method `text.count + 1` times.
This is probably fine,
but you could reduce the number of calls to `commonPrefix`
by using a divide and conquer strategy.

For example, consider you have paths `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn`.
You could call `commonPrefix` for each pair, to get `n / 2` results.
Then you could call `commonPrefix` for each of those pairs.
And so on, until there is only one pair left:

```
p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8
|__|  |__|  |__|  |__|
 |_____|     |_____|
    |___________|
          |
          = the common prefix
```

Admittedly, this might be overkill for your use case.